# How to get the type of the dragged item (file or text) when the dragover event fires?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a textarea that detects if an element (e. g. image **file**) is dragged over it.

```
// drag and drop for upload
$('body').on('dragover', 'textarea', function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    // indicator for user
    $('.drophere').show();
});
```

The problem is that the indicator to drop shows also up when text is dragged over the textarea (and not a file).

I thought I could check the type of the dragged item.

The [HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations) says:

> The drag data contains two pieces of information, the type (or format) of the data, and the data's value. The format is a type string (such as text/plain for text data), and the value is a string of text.

However, using `console.log( e.originalEvent.dataTransfer );` in the code above does not reveal any data type.

The attribute `types` is always empty for text dragged but also for an image file dragged.

[image]

Where can I find the file type or plain/text type?

Comment: You can use the typeof operator to find the data type of a JavaScript variable

Comment: Using `typeof(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer)` always throws `object`. I don't see where that should help.

Comment: Minimal [reproducible](https://codesandbox.io/s/js-drag-drop-example-g0ucj) would be nice. Are you dragging things from same page or from desktop into the browser window?

Comment: Files from Desktop. Text from same page.

Comment: I setup a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/47dq60oc/) and cannot reproduce this. For me types is being populated, either ["Files"] for files or ["text/plain", "text/html"] for text. Can you setup a fiddle that shows the problem? Is it in all browsers?

Comment: @jcbdrn Thanks a lot. It works now!  And I have no idea why it didn't work before (Chrome 98, Windows 10).

Answer (score 3):

you can't view type or items stored in dataTransfer object since when your drag is stopped javascript changes this object values and because objects are referenced in javascript you see the changed value after dropping the text.
if you notice when you print data in the console they have values but when expanding objects they are empty.

[image]

so you can check the format in runtime but for debugging you can use other methods to store this object like clone object without reference. like that :

```
var types = $.extend(true, {}, e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types)    
var item = $.extend(true, {}, e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0])

console.log(types)
console.log(item)
```

[image]

Comment: `console.log( e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types );`  finally worked.